# How can I run an OS command, such as CHMOD, from PL/SQL?

Tags: unix, plsql

How I can run a `chmod` command from a PL/SQL block?

Comment: Lookup http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_execute_operating_system_os_command_oracle.htm and https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2008/06/04/how-to-run-an-os-command-from-pl-sql

Answer (score 6):

**dbms_scheduler way:**

```
begin    
    dbms_scheduler.create_job (
       job_name    => 'ext_tasks_job',
       job_type    => 'executable',
       job_action  => '/bin/sh',
       number_of_arguments => 2,
       auto_drop   => true);    
    dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value ('ext_tasks_job', 1, '-c');
    dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value ('ext_tasks_job', 2, 'chmod 777 /somedir/some.file');
    dbms_scheduler.run_job ('ext_tasks_job'); 
end;
```

[source](https://community.oracle.com/message/10399248#10399248)

Comment: www.orafaq.com proposes several more workarounds for this under the heading: 
[Can one execute an operation system command from PL/SQL](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PL/SQL_FAQ#Can_one_execute_an_operating_system_command_from_PL.2FSQL.3F)